# Passing test class to be run as a parameter to Maven -Dtest

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have 2 test classes in my project that I want to run through jenkins, each with a particular profile (because they have different set of dependencies). I tried to create a parameter "Class_To-Run" which will have the name of class to be run in the pre-steps and then executed project as:

```
mvn clean compile test -Dtest=$Class_To_Run -P profileUsed
```

which throws the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) on project SparkTest: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.)
However, if a specify the name of the class to be run in the command itself (-Dtest=ClassName), the project runs successfully. Am I committing some mistake? How do I make it parameterised?
```

Following is the log after build fails:

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) on project SparkTest: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) on project SparkTest: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven33Launcher.main(Maven33Launcher.java:129)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main.launch(Maven33Main.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:139)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:70)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:207)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:53)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:358)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:847)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 31 more
```

Comment: Could you check the value of your variable? What is the result of `echo $Class_To_Run && mvn test -Dtest=$Class_To_Run`? Another thing to test is `mvn test -Dtest=$Class_To_Run -X`. In the debug output you should see a line `[DEBUG]   (s) test = abc` (with abc the name of the class)

Comment: when i say echo $Class_To_Run, it gives me the name of the class which I want to run but while executing maven command, it's not being expanded: pom.xml clean -Dtest=$Class_To_Run test -P profileUsed. It should have the value instead of the variable Class_To_Run.

Comment: have added the log @werner . I guess its unable to get name of the test class when its parameterised as the variable "Class_To_Run" is not being expanded to its value while jenkins is executing maven

Comment: Also, I'm unable to something as: [DEBUG] (s) test in the console output

Comment: Are you sure that you have enabled the debug output with `-X`? You should be able to see some output like [this](https://books.google.de/books?id=cBvZ4s72Z0gC&pg=PA201&lpg=PA201&dq=maven+debug+output&source=bl&ots=iIEZyLrhfC&sig=9smmj3ukpttptiFKSSYReqDU-0I&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRsJ7Og5rbAhVqK8AKHclcD54Q6AEwCHoFCAEQnwE#v=onepage&q=maven%20debug%20output&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured it out. As I said in comments above that the variable ("Class_To_Run") was not being expanded to its value while the maven command was being executed by jenkins. The problem was that I had declared the variable in execute shell part in Pre Steps of jenkins job configuration. The parameters that you create in the general step of jenkins job are only accessible in the build step.